# Angular property is missing

Tags: angular, web, webapi

I have following model.

```
export class Instructor{
firstname:string;
lastname:string;
}

export class Course {
ID: number;
title: string;
crn: string;
instructor:Instructor;   
}
```

And I want to reset a form  by using this method.

```
 this.service.formData = {

  ID : null,
  title : '',
  crn : '' 
  }
```

I have to add instructor property, and by using this property I have to set firstname and lastname = ' '; .in above parenthesis. But I dont know how. Kindly, help me.

Comment: Assuming you are using reactive forms, Would you please provide a working example?

Comment: Angular forms provides a `reset` method, provided you have the form set up properly. It seems your problem is more about initializing the form than being about resetting the form. Please look at Angular FormBuilder to build reactive form.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solver by using instructor : {firstname:'',lastname:''} in above method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```js
this.service.formData = {
  ID : null,
  title : '',
  crn : '',
  instructor: {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
  },
};
```